# Create FK relationship during migration

Tags: python, django, django-models

On migration I need to create a relationship between activity and organisation where organisation has not been created. Below is what I have so far. I now need so somehow set the `default=` to the new organisation created? i.e.

```
field=models.ForeignKey(related_name='activities', to='orss.Organisation' default=temp_org_just_created
```

**Is this possible? If so how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of migrations, schema and data migrations. You'll need to run your schema migration first, and the data migration afterwards.

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)